# Fonts showing in Font Book but not in Finder

Tags: finder, font, font-book

I randomly found a font called 'Baloo' in Font Book, yet I can't seem to find out how it's been installed.

When I click on one of it's variants in Font Book, it says that I need to 'download' the font, and presents me with a download button like the below.

The font doesn't appear to be in my library folder and I can't find the file for it anywhere else. Font Book also as greyed out the `Show in Finder` feature for this font.

I can use the font fine in any CreativeCloud program, but it doesn't appear to be an Adobe Font.

Does anyone know why this might have happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does provide additional fonts as optional installs that can be downloaded if you want. From the linked Apple Support document, Baloo is one of those.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210192

If you have Creative Cloud, then you have access to Adobe's font library: CC apps can install any font for their own use directly from Adobe Fonts, independently of macOS's font management.

Comment: Ahh I see! Looks like it must have been since I installed Catalina then